# jQuery .click()/.on("click"...) I need help swapping text on alternate clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I am trying to accomplish is something 'like'

```
$("button .toggleExcerpt)
    .toggle( function FIRST() {
        do first function...
    } , function SECOND() {
        do second function...
```

But since it's deprecated, I don't know what alternative to use. Ive tried using if/else inside of a .on("click", function()... but didn't seem to work. 
jQuery:

```
var readMore = "<span class='readMore'>read about the solution...</span>";
var readLess = "<span class='readLess'>hide full description...</span>";

//".toggleExcerpt" is an empty <button> in the HTML

$(".toggleExcerpt").append(readMore);

$(".toggleExcerpt")
    .on("click", function (event) {
        $(this).contents(".readMore")
            .replaceWith(readLess);
        console.log("readMore ran");
    })
    .on("click", function (event) {
         $(this).contents(".readLess")
             .replaceWith(readMore);
         console.log("readLess ran");            
    })
```

Both of the click events are logging to the console, so I know that the first event is running, and then is quickly replaced by the second event, but I would love to make these (or simply the text inside the span) to alternate....

I've already looked at [this suggestion](https://css-tricks.com/swapping-out-text-five-different-ways/), but I am not sure how to implement it in my example, nor if this particular jQuery implementation is what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try letting a boolean swap back and forth for you?

Here's your snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var readMore = "<span class='readMore'>read about the solution...</span>";
  var readLess = "<span class='readLess'>hide full description...</span>";
  var more = true;

  //".toggleExcerpt" is an empty <button> in the HTML

  $("#toggleExcerpt").append(readMore);

  $("#toggleExcerpt")
    .on("click", function(event) {
      if (more) {
        $(this).contents(".readMore")
          .replaceWith(readLess);
        console.log("readMore ran");
        more = false;
      } else {
        $(this).contents(".readLess")
          .replaceWith(readMore);
        console.log("readLess ran");
        more = true;
      }
    })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="toggleExcerpt"></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this snippet:

```js
var readMore = "read about the solution...";
var readLess = "hide full description...";
var excerptState = true;
//".toggleExcerpt" is an empty <button> in the HTML

$(".toogleExcerpt").html(readMore);

$(".toogleExcerpt").click(function () {

    $(this).html( excerptState ? readLess : readMore );
    
    // invert state
    excerptState = !excerptState
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="toogleExcerpt"></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

To check the class is exists or not , you have to use `.hasClass()` . if `class` found,use `.remove()` to remove that element and `.append()` to add another.

**For example, You can try this code :**

```
var readMore = "<span class='readMore'>read about the solution...</span>";
var readLess = "<span class='readLess'>hide full description...</span>";

//".toggleExcerpt" is an empty <button> in the HTML

$(".toggleExcerpt").append(readMore);

$(".toggleExcerpt")
    .on("click", function (event) {
        if($(this).find('span').hasClass('readmore') === true){
          $(this).find('span.readmore').remove();
          $(this).append(readLess);
        }else{
          $(this).find('span.readLess').remove();
          $(this).append(readMore);
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I created a solution for you.

Just use a flag var that increments by 1, and check if it is odd or even and depending on if it is odd or even it will alternate the text for you onclick:

```js
var readMore = "<span class='readMore'>read about the solution...</span>";
var readLess = "<span class='readLess'>hide full description...</span>";

//".toggleExcerpt" is an empty <button> in the HTML

var flag = 0;

$(".toggleExcerpt").append(readMore);

$(".toggleExcerpt")
  .on("click", function(event) {
    if (flag % 2 == 0) {
      $(this).contents(".readMore")
        .replaceWith(readLess);
      console.log("readMore ran");
    } else {
      $(this).contents(".readLess")
        .replaceWith(readMore);
      console.log("readLess ran");
    }
    flag++;
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="toggleExcerpt" style="width:300px">
```